# unable to recover disk space postgresql

Tags: postgresql, disk, diskspace

The system is FC21 with Postgresql 9.3.9. The cluster has 6 databases and uses 38 GB of storage in the pgsql directory. Recently over 20GB of redundant data has been removed. Each db has been vacuumed with a 'vacuum all' command twice, additionally the entire cluster has been vacuumed twice with a vacuumdb -a command. All ran successfully. Postgresql has been stopped and restarted.
For verification a pg_dumpall command creates an 12GB file.
All the tables from one db were removed:

> select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('db'));

Shows over 6GB remaining. 
How can the space be recovered? It seems unreasonable to have to do a pg_restore to recover the space. I have read and re-read the 'recovering disk space' document.

Answer (score 0):

A `VACUUM` command will only reclaim space that is at the end of table-files. You will want `VACUUM FULL` or `vacuumdb -f`.

You might also want to consider `reindexdb` since all this row rewriting might leave your indexes a little bloated.

Comment: `reindex` is no longer necessary after `vacuum full` from 8.4 (?) onward. It basically does a `cluster` behind the scenes. Also, if you're going to `vacuum full` and you expect to add data back in future, consider altering the tables and indexes to set a lower `fillfactor` so there's space to add data throughout. It can *massively* improve write performance at the cost of some disk space and read performance.

Comment: That did not work. The db started out at 38GB and ended at 38GB. It took a very long time to run and no errors were reported. The -v option shows significant activity but no space was recovered. To check the vacuumdb -afv was also rerun as user postgres.

Comment: How do you know that you have space to reclaim? How did you measure that?